# Python while loop won't exit (Beginner)

Tags: python, while-loop

The `while` loop at the end doesn't exit and I can't figure out why.

```
import sys

def is_prime(n):
    if n == 3:
        return True
    elif n == 4:
        return False
    else:
        for i in xrange(2,n):
            if n % i == 0:
                return False
        return True

primes = [2, 3]

counter = int(raw_input("Which prime number would you like to find? "))

while len(primes) < counter:
    for i in xrange(primes[-1], sys.maxint):
        if is_prime(i):
            primes.append(i)

print(primes[-1])
```

Comment: wrt optimizations; there are also far more efficient algorithms for [Primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Martin Konecny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30043561/908494) explains, your loop requires calculating all the primes up to `sys.maxint`, which takes a very, very long time (especially if you're on a 64-bit platform!).

But really, you don't *need* primes up to `sys.maxint`, or even primes up to 10000. With his solution, you're going to calculate the first 1229 primes even if you only need the first 7, which means it'll take way longer than necessary. Worse, you're *only* going to calculate the first 1229 primes, even if you need the 1400th, which means you'll end up in an infinite loop looking for the next prime under 10000 forever even though there are no more primes under 10000.

The key here is to break out of the *inner* loop as soon as possible, so you can get back to the *outer* loop. The inner loop is checking whether you have a *big enough* prime, which isn't relevant to your problem; the outer loop is checking whether you have *enough* primes. So you want to check the outer loop after each prime that you find.

One way to do that is to change the inner loop so it just `break`s out after one prime, giving you a chance to check the `len` again:

```
while len(primes) < counter:
    for i in xrange(primes[-1], sys.maxint):
        if is_prime(i):
            primes.append(i)
            break
```

In fact, if you do this, you can even replace the limit with an *infinite* range, and it will still complete.

One more thing: You have a bug in the inner loop: `xrange(primes[-1], sys.maxint)` includes `primes[-1]`. And `primes[-1]` is obviously prime. So, you're just going to keep appending the same value over and over. You need a `+ 1` there.

So:

```
while len(primes) < counter:
    for i in itertools.count(primes[-1]+1)
        if is_prime(i):
            primes.append(i)
            break
```

---

A better solution to this problem would be to use a real prime sieve rather than a divisor test. A sieve effectively keeps a lookahead mapping of the next multiples of each prime found so far, so you can very quickly determine whether N is prime if you've already checked all the values up to N-1. But doing that is a much larger answer. :)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that the `while` condition doesn't get checked at the end of every `for` loop iteration. "Local vs. global" always gets me.  The `break` solved everything. Much appreciated.

Comment: @conjenks: Right, it only gets checked after the whole `for` loop is done. `while` can't "reach into" the code inside its block and break out as soon as its condition becomes false, it just checks the condition, runs the whole block, and repeats.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it won't exit is because your search space for potential primes numbers is way too big. Your desktop is not that fast! They have supercomputers trying to calculate this stuff.

```
for i in xrange(primes[-1], sys.maxint):
```

To start with, try changing this to something more reasonable:

```
for i in xrange(primes[-1], 10000):
```

You will see your loop does actually exit.

**EDIT:**

There are some nice optimizations you can add to this problem. First, you should increment by 2 to skip all even numbers:

```
for i in xrange(primes[-1], sys.maxint, 2):
```

Second, you only need to test for divisors up to the **square root** of the potential prime number.

```
for i in xrange(2,n**(0.5)):
```

The reason for this is that any two numbers whose product is `n`, one of those will always be less than the square root of `n` - therefore if you haven't found a divisor by the time you hit the square root of `n`, you can stop. This greatly reduces your search space for larger numbers.

Comment: This isn't really the problem—and it's not a great solution, because it means getting the 8th prime is just as expensive as getting the 1229th, while getting the 1230th will go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Got it! The issue was that I was not aware that the `while` condition does not get checked at the end of every `for` loop iteration. I was never trying to find _that_ many prime numbers. A simple addition of a `break` after the `primes.append(i)` solved it, even with the ridiculous range. Lesson learned. Thanks!

Comment: @abarnert - you are correct. I missed the part where he is trying to find a specific prime number, not all of them. Can you briefly expand on the 1230th prime going into an infinite loop?

Comment: @MartinKonecny: The 1230th prime number is `10007`. So, the outer loop will see that you only have 1229 primes, the inner loop will go from 9974 to 10000 and see no new primes and exit, the outer loop will see that you only have 1229 primes, ad infinitum.

Comment: Although I think he has another bug, where he'll just keep appending `9973` onto the list each time, in which case he _will_ actually return, just with the wrong number (for any input >1229, it'll return 9973).